# How to change the Lab value of a solid-color layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an existing Photoshop file which contains several layers. Each layer is a square shape filled with a solid color. I want to change the color of the squares to Lab values. For example I want one square to be filled with L=50, a=0, b=-20. How do I do this? I am a Photoshop novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the layers are made :

-> If they are **simple pixel** layers and look like these :

[image: Simple Layer]

Choose your LAB color on the color tool :

[image: color tool]

Then lock the pixels on the selected layer, and use alt/option + delete on the keyboard to fill the pixels with your color. (If you don't lock the pixels, this will fill all the canvas, not only the existing pixels)

[image: lock the pixels]

-> If they are **dynamic layers** and look like these :

[image: Dynamic layers]

Simply double clic on the color thumbnail and you'll open the color window.

[image: Double Clic]

Comment: They are simple pixel layers. Thanks!